# Heroku HTTP request with large request body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn

I am running a ruby on rails app with unicorn server on Heroku.

Scenario: Client sends a HTTP POST request with a large request body.

My understanding:

1. Heroku router establishes a HTTP connection with client and forwards it to the dyno
2. 30 sec counter starts
3. Dyno starts reading the request body from client through the connection
4. if client is slow and takes greater than 30 secs to transfer the request body Heroku issues a HTTP 503 error and closes the connection

Is my understanding right? Or is it the case that Heroku only starts the timeout counter after the dyno has read the request body?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#router):

> HTTP requests have an initial 30 second window in which the web
>   process must return response data (either the completed response or
>   some amount of response data to indicate that the process is active).
>   Processes that do not send response data within the initial 30-second
>   window will see an H12 error in their logs.

I think it's designed to prevent dynos being tied up for any particular length of time

My understanding is the timer starts as soon as you send a request to the server. Once the request is `routed`, the timer begins to count down until you start getting data back